# MySQL / MariaDB InnoDB indexes stops working

Tags: mysql, innodb, indexing, mariadb, xtradb

I am experiencing weird behaviour from my MySQL/MariaDB InnoDB/XtraDB. Recently switched to MariaDB 5.5. The switch made the server overall more performent, but I still have this problem.

One particular tables index seems to break every now and then. And after a while, it fixes it self.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE article_inventory;` gives

```
CREATE TABLE `article_inventory` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `article_variant_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `season_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `warehouse_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `quantity` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `unique_inventory_idx` (`article_variant_id`, `season_id`, `warehouse_id`),
    INDEX `article_variant_id_idx` (`article_variant_id`),
    INDEX `article_inventory_season_id_idx` (`season_id`),
    INDEX `article_inventory_warehouse_id_idx` (`warehouse_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `article_inventory_article_variant_id_article_variant_id` FOREIGN KEY (`article_variant_id`) REFERENCES `article_variant` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `article_inventory_season_id_season_id` FOREIGN KEY (`season_id`) REFERENCES `season` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `article_inventory_warehouse_id_warehouse_id` FOREIGN KEY (`warehouse_id`) REFERENCES `warehouse` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3827622858;
```

**EDIT:** Majority of SELECT queries is made against this table. Big updates are made every hour. Some times VERY large updates.

Running this query:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM article a
    INNER JOIN article_variant a2 
        ON a.style_id = a2.style_id
    INNER JOIN article_block a3 
        ON a2.po = a3.po
    INNER JOIN color c 
        ON a2.color_id = c.id
    INNER JOIN size s 
        ON a2.size_id = s.id
    INNER JOIN article_group a4 
        ON a2.id = a4.article_variant_id AND (a4.season_id = 6)
    INNER JOIN article_inventory a5 
        ON a2.id = a5.article_variant_id AND (((a5.warehouse_id = 5 OR a5.warehouse_id = 1) AND a5.season_id = 6))
    INNER JOIN article_date a6 
        ON a.style_id = a6.style_id AND ((a6.pricelist_id = 5 AND a6.season_id = 6))
    INNER JOIN article_price a7 
        ON a.style_id = a7.style_id AND ((a7.pricelist_id = 5 AND a7.season_id = 6))
    INNER JOIN pricelist p 
        ON a7.pricelist_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN concept c2 
        ON a4.concept_id = c2.id
    INNER JOIN category c3 
        ON a4.category_id = c3.id
    LEFT JOIN order_cart_row o 
        ON a2.id = o.article_variant_id AND (o.order_id = 17035)
    LEFT JOIN shortlist s2 
        ON a.id = s2.article_id AND (s2.order_id = 17035)
WHERE ((a2.is_canceled <> 1 AND a4.is_canceled <> 1) OR o.quantity IS NOT NULL) AND c2.id = 2
GROUP BY a.id
```

... should execute in about 0.5-1.0sec, and give me an explain similar to this:

```
id select_type table  type     possible_keys                                                                                               key                                 key_len    ref                                  rowsExtra
1  SIMPLE      p      const    PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             8          const                                1   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE      c2     const    PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             8          const                                1   Using index                            
1  SIMPLE      a3     index    PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             98         NULL                                 1031Using where                            
1  SIMPLE      a2     ref      PRIMARY,unique_variant_idx,color_id_idx,style_id_idx,size_id_idx,article_variant_po_idx                     article_variant_po_idx              98         wsp_stage.a3.po                      14  Using where                            
1  SIMPLE      s      eq_ref   PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             11         wsp_stage.a2.size_id                 1   Using index                            
1  SIMPLE      c      eq_ref   PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             11         wsp_stage.a2.color_id                1                                          
1  SIMPLE      o      eq_ref   unique_rows_idx,article_variant_id_idx,order_id_idx                                                         unique_rows_idx                     16         const,wsp_stage.a2.id                1   Using index                            
1  SIMPLE      a      eq_ref   unique_style_idx                                                                                            unique_style_idx                    767        wsp_stage.a2.style_id                1   Using index                            
1  SIMPLE      a6     ref      article_season_pricelist_unique_idx,season_id_idx,pricelist_id_idx,style_id_idx                             article_season_pricelist_unique_idx 784        wsp_stage.a2.style_id,const,const    1   Using index                            
1  SIMPLE      a7     ref      article_season_pricelist_unique_idx,season_id_idx,pricelist_id_idx,style_id_idx                             article_season_pricelist_unique_idx 784        wsp_stage.a2.style_id,const,const    1   Using index                            
1  SIMPLE      a4     eq_ref   unique_group_idx,one_per_season_idx,category_id_idx,concept_id_idx,season_id_idx,article_variant_id_idx     one_per_season_idx                  16         wsp_stage.a2.id,const                1   Using index                            
1  SIMPLE      c3     eq_ref   PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             8          wsp_stage.a4.category_id             1   Using index                            
1  SIMPLE      s2     ref      shortlist_article_id_idx                                                                                    shortlist_article_id_idx            8          wsp_stage.a.id                       10  Using where                            
1  SIMPLE      a5     ref      unique_inventory_idx,article_variant_id_idx,article_inventory_season_id_idx,article_inventory_warehouse_id_iunique_inventory_idx                17         wsp_stage.a2.id,const                8   Using where
```

When everything is working as it should, article_inventory (alias a5) uses `unique_inventory_idx`, or `article_variant_id_idx`. Both should give me about 5-100 examined rows.

But every now and then, something happens, and the same query takes up to about 30sec, and gives me this explain:

```
id select_type table  type     possible_keys                                                                                               key                                 key_len  ref                                  rows    Extra
1  SIMPLE      p      const    PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             8        const                                1       Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE      c2     const    PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             8        const                                1       Using index
1  SIMPLE      a5     ref      unique_inventory_idx,article_variant_id_idx,article_inventory_season_id_idx,article_inventory_warehouse_id_iarticle_inventory_season_id_idx     8        const                                6718732 Using where
1  SIMPLE      a4     eq_ref   unique_group_idx,one_per_season_idx,category_id_idx,concept_id_idx,season_id_idx,article_variant_id_idx     one_per_season_idx                  16       wsp_stage.a5.article_variant_id,const1       Using where
1  SIMPLE      c3     eq_ref   PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             8        wsp_stage.a4.category_id             1       Using index
1  SIMPLE      a2     eq_ref   PRIMARY,unique_variant_idx,color_id_idx,style_id_idx,size_id_idx,article_variant_po_idx                     PRIMARY                             8        wsp_stage.a5.article_variant_id      1       
1  SIMPLE      c      eq_ref   PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             11       wsp_stage.a2.color_id                1       Using index
1  SIMPLE      a      eq_ref   unique_style_idx                                                                                            unique_style_idx                    767      wsp_stage.a2.style_id                1       Using index
1  SIMPLE      a6     ref      article_season_pricelist_unique_idx,season_id_idx,pricelist_id_idx,style_id_idx                             article_season_pricelist_unique_idx 784      wsp_stage.a2.style_id,const,const    1       Using index
1  SIMPLE      a7     ref      article_season_pricelist_unique_idx,season_id_idx,pricelist_id_idx,style_id_idx                             article_season_pricelist_unique_idx 784      wsp_stage.a2.style_id,const,const    1       Using index
1  SIMPLE      s      eq_ref   PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             11       wsp_stage.a2.size_id                 1       Using index
1  SIMPLE      a3     eq_ref   PRIMARY                                                                                                     PRIMARY                             98       wsp_stage.a2.po                      1       Using index
1  SIMPLE      o      eq_ref   unique_rows_idx,article_variant_id_idx,order_id_idx                                                         unique_rows_idx                     16       const,wsp_stage.a5.article_variant_id1       Using where
1  SIMPLE      s2     ref      shortlist_article_id_idx                                                                                    shortlist_article_id_idx            8        wsp_stage.a.id                       7       Using where
```

`article_inventory` (a5) is now using `article_inventory_season_id_idx`. A very very bad index, as it is the second least specific of them all. Gives me 6718732 examined rows.

`my.ini:`

```
[mysqld]
datadir="W:/mariadb/data/"
port=3306
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
default_storage_engine=innodb
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5000M
innodb_log_file_size=52428800
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_file_format=Barracuda

[client]
port=3307
```

Comment: Is this table heavily updated?

Comment: Yes, i was just about to update the question. Loads of reads and large periodical `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATEs`.

Comment: could you replace `article_inventory a5 ON a2.id = a5.article_variant_id AND (((a5.warehouse_id = 5 OR a5.warehouse_id = 1) AND a5.season_id = 6))` with `(select list_of_cols from article_inventory a5 ON a2.id = a5.article_variant_id AND a5.warehouse_id = 5 and a5.season_id = 6
 union all
 select list_of_cols from article_inventory a5 ON a2.id = a5.article_variant_id AND a5.warehouse_id = 1 and a5.season_id = 6) as a5`. I would try to investigate the following: 1) create another index on (warehouse_id + season_id) 2) doing pre-filtering with table using where and only than join with other tbl.

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly the index is not broken. This is probably related to MySQL statistics on the table suggesting to the query optimizer to use the wrong index. Now before we move onto possible solutions lets first understand what is causing it.

When MySQL runs a query it looks at the statistics of that table to determine which indexes are appropriate for the query and then based on the recommendations choose the correct index. Table statistics contain information such as index cardinality and the cost associated with using the index. MySQL will look at these statistics every time it runs a query to determine the best path of execution.

Now since indexes are actual data structures stored on disk when you update, insert and delete from these indexes their statistics change. This could possibly the root cause of the problem. InnoDB updates statistics on the fly by doing 8 random deep dives into the index structures. MyISAM does it differently. See this link for some more information around this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/from-where-does-the-mysql-query-optimizer-read-index-statistics

You mentioned you do large inserts with on duplicate update every once in a while. I suspect that either during the insert or after the insert happens there is a small period where the innodb statistics for the table is out of date or being compiled. This might be why you are seeing the sporadic change from one index to the infective index. Your statistics are incorrect at that point and the query optimizer is making the wrong choice.

Go google the following:

```
mysql statistics update
```

There is a whole stack of links with more details about this and it is some good reading.

I have seen this happen before on databases and it is not a BUG it is just something to be aware of.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Explicitly call ANALYSE TABLE on the tables in question after the bulk insert with on duplicate update statements. Running this command directly after the updates might bring your statistics into the correct form so it suggests the right index. The down side is that your system might actually be recompiling statistics twice which is kin of wasting resources. Remember I am not sure if this problem occurs after or during the insert statement.
2. Force the use of the correct index in your select statement. You can force MySQL to use the correct index the whole time. However this is a bad idea. At some point another index might become more optimized for your query and since you now are effectively hardcoding the index to use into the query it will become a problem later.
3. Leave it as is, this might sound strange but is a query running for 30sec a disaster? It might be depending on your requirements but if 30sec is ok for the query to run why try and fix it? Remember if it isn’t broke don’t fix it philosophy.

I hope this makes sense post a comment if you need more clarification.....

Comment: Interesting read. It lead me to do what i did to calm the problem down.

Comment: My situation looked like this, my table is VERY volatile. Loads of reads and loads of inserts/updates. Grows quickly. But the data is not historically critical. I calmed it down by truncating it entirely and recreated the data from our master source. It resulted in the table being shrunk 80%. (bad maintenance from my side for not doing this earlier). In affect, this resulted in either index performing roughly the same. Even a full table scan is acceptable (disabled index with USE INDEX()). Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: "Leave it as is, this might sound strange but is a query running for 30sec a disaster? It might be depending on your requirements but if 30sec is ok for the query to run why try and fix it? Remember if it isn’t broke don’t fix it philosophy."

Seriously?  I hope you were in a funny mood when you wrote this

Comment: @Dominique so if I query a 1TB with 100 000 000 rows in and I am joining that for a report that runs once a month for a CEO that looks at it for 5 minutes if it take 30 seconds what is the problem? Some queries just dont need to be highly optimized, its call over engineering. Remember adding new indexes incurs new maintenance. Why would you incur more maintenance for gains that no one will notice?